# Symfony2 From Collection has no elements

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to implement Form Collections. I have members and each member can have multiple memberships. The given member object for "createForm()" has an array with memberships which are correctly fetched from database. The member form gets is shown correct, but it seems that form.memberships is empty. It doesn't even render the "Test".

**Controller**

```
public function memberAction($id) {
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $user_provider = $this->get('webservice_user_provider');

    if ($id === "new") {
        $member = new WebserviceUser();
        $name = "Neues Mitlgied";
    } else if (intval($id) != 0) {
        $member = $user_provider->getUserById(intval($id));
        $member->getMemberships();
        $name = $member->getName() . " " . $member->getLastname();
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('No Member found!');
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new MemberType($this->get('webservice_config_provider')), $member);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('bow_exciting_fit_member', array('id' => $user_provider->persistMember($form->getViewData()))));
    }

    return $this->render('BOWExcitingFitBundle:Default:member.html.twig', array(                    
                "member" => $member,
                "form" => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

**MemberType**

```
class MemberType extends AbstractType {

function __construct(\BOW\ExcitingFitBundle\Webservice\WebserviceConfigProvider $config) {
    $this->config = $config;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {     

   ... MORE CODE ...

    $builder->add('memberships', 'collection', array(
        'type' => new MembershipType($this->config),
        'by_reference' => false,
        'allow_add' => true));

    ... MORE CODE ...
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'BOW\ExcitingFitBundle\Webservice\WebserviceUser',
    ));
}

public function getName() {
    return 'member';
}

}
```

**MembershipType**

```
class MembershipType extends AbstractType {

function __construct(\BOW\ExcitingFitBundle\Webservice\WebserviceConfigProvider $config) {
    $this->config = $config;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    ... MORE CODE ...

    $builder->add('id', 'hidden');
    $builder->add('user', 'hidden');

    ... MORE CODE ...

}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'BOW\ExcitingFitBundle\Webservice\WebserviceMembership',
    ));
}

public function getName() {
    return 'membership';
}

}
```

**Template**

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
  <div class="ui divided list memberships" data-prototype="{{ include('BOWExcitingFitBundle:Form:membership-prototype.html.twig', { 'form': form.memberships.vars.prototype })|e }}">      
    {% for membership in form.memberships %}
      Test
      {{ include('BOWExcitingFitBundle:Form:membership-prototype.html.twig', { 'form': membership }) }}
    {% endfor %}  
  </div>               
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if I don't use Doctrine, I had to use an arrayCollection() instead of an array for the memberships.